# Invalid use of group function on sum function

Tags: mysql

My SQL query is returning an error **#1111 - Invalid use of group function** when summing the rows on result

This Query is working fine and returning many rows.

```
SELECT credit.Amount - SUM( COALESCE( creditreceived.Amount, 0 ) ) AS 
AmountReceivable FROM credit LEFT JOIN creditreceived ON credit.ID = 
creditreceived.CreditID WHERE credit.CompanyID =  '1' GROUP BY credit.id
```

Result Image:
http://oi65.tinypic.com/qplyli.jpg

I want to sum these rows, to do so I am using this query

```
SELECT SUM( credit.Amount - SUM( COALESCE( creditreceived.Amount, 0 ) ) ) AS
AmountReceivable FROM credit LEFT JOIN creditreceived ON credit.ID = 
creditreceived.CreditID WHERE credit.CompanyID =  '1' GROUP BY credit.id
```

this is returning error **#1111 - Invalid use of group function**

Comment: Consider providing create and insert statements and a desired result

Comment: Desired result is the sum of all rows shown in picture

Comment: I can only refer you to the comment I made previously

Comment: It think the problem is not the group by. Try `SUM( credit.Amount - COALESCE( creditreceived.Amount, 0 ) )  AS..`

Comment: @GerdK Please post this as an answer. It works, I want to accept it :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It think the problem is not the group by. Try

`SUM( credit.Amount - COALESCE( creditreceived.Amount, 0 ) ) AS..`

Comment: Thanks :) Final query becomes:

`SELECT COALESCE( SUM( credit.Amount - COALESCE( creditreceived.Amount, 0 ) ) , 0 ) AS AmountReceivable
FROM credit
LEFT JOIN creditreceived ON credit.ID = creditreceived.CreditID
WHERE credit.CompanyID =  '1'`