# How to fix problem with sum, length and group by

Tags: mysql, sql

Field  contracts  is a text, value is strings separated by "," .

**A query:**

```
select sum( if( length(dapps.contracts) = 
       sum(length(replace(dapps.contracts,',',''))) , 1 , length(dapps.contracts) 
     - sum(length(replace(dapps.contracts,',',''))) ) ) as f1 
  from dapps 
 group by id
```

**show :**

```
Error in query (1111): Invalid use of group function
```

Need a one  level query

This query work fine

```
select sum(f1)
from (
 select if( length(dapps.contracts) = 
        sum(length(replace(dapps.contracts,',',''))) , 1 , length(dapps.contracts) 
      - sum(length(replace(dapps.contracts,',',''))) ) as f1 
   from dapps 
  group by id
) tb1​
```

Need query without subquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid use of group function on sum function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390845/invalid-use-of-group-function-on-sum-function)

Comment: try this `select id,sum( if( length(dapps.contracts) = ... `

Comment: You can't nest `sum()` inside another `sum()`.

Comment: Can you show some sample data and the desired output?

Comment: Why do you need a query without subquery?

Comment: The subquery doesn't look valid to me, either. You're picking a random row in each group and checking whether the length of its `contracts` column is equal to the sum of the replaced contracts in all the rows of the group.